# how to fix issue with search input with case sensitive search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey so i'm having issue with search input let say if i want to search for "Car" if i type just car all lower case nothing shows up same thing for upper case below is sample of my code as well as link for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1dtqxh9/4/ any help will be appreciated

HTML

```
<div class="search">
<form>
<input id="search" type="text" /><input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
</div>

<div id="grid">
<figure>
<div class="image">
<img class="IMG" src="LINK" />
<span class="IMGBOTTOM"></span>
</div>
<div class="POST">
<div class="INFO">
<h3><a href="LINK">Oranges</a></h3>
<p><b class="TYPE">Type: </b>Fruit</p>
<p><b class="location">Location: </b>Goracaries Stores </p>
<p><b class="taste">Tastes: </b>Like Orangishhh</p>
</div>
<div class="postbottom">
<div class="rate"><a class="ratefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="share"><a class="sharefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
    <figure>
<div class="image">
<img class="IMG" src="LINK" />
<span class="IMGBOTTOM"></span>
</div>
<div class="POST">
<div class="INFO">
<h3><a href="LINK">Car</a></h3>
<p><b class="TYPE">Type: </b>Auto Mobile</p>
<p><b class="location">Location: </b>Dealers </p>
<p><b class="taste">Tastes: </b>No Taste </p>
</div>
<div class="postbottom">
<div class="rate"><a class="ratefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Speedy or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="share"><a class="sharefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Speedy or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
    <figure>
<div class="image">
<img class="IMG" src="LINK" />
<span class="IMGBOTTOM"></span>
</div>
<div class="POST">
<div class="INFO">
<h3><a href="LINK">House</a></h3>
<p><b class="TYPE">Type: </b>Home</p>
<p><b class="location">Location: </b>Casa </p>
<p><b class="taste">Tastes: </b>Home Sweet Home</p>
</div>
<div class="postbottom">
<div class="rate"><a class="ratefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="share"><a class="sharefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
    <figure>
<div class="image">
<img class="IMG" src="LINK" />
<span class="IMGBOTTOM"></span>
</div>
<div class="POST">
<div class="INFO">
<h3><a href="LINK">Sky</a></h3>
<p><b class="TYPE">Type: </b>Nature</p>
<p><b class="location">Location: </b>SKy</p>
<p><b class="taste">Tastes: </b>Rain</p>
</div>
<div class="postbottom">
<div class="rate"><a class="ratefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="share"><a class="sharefruits"
href="links">
<span id="duhh" class="duhhh"></span><br>
    <span id="blahh" class="nahh">Like or Naa?</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
```

JavaScript

```
var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("figure");

search.on("keyup", function() {
  var terms = search.val();
  if (terms == '') {
    listItems.show();
  } else {
    listItems.hide(); 
    $("figure:contains('" + terms + "')").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: If possible, just convert both to lower or uppercase, then case will match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One choice is to use .filter() and toLowerCase()

```
search.on("keyup", function () {
    var terms = search.val().toLowerCase();
    if (terms == '') {
        listItems.show();
    } else {
        listItems.hide();
        $("figure").filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(terms) > -1
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8pd9hfdx/)

Another choice is to use a regex

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

var search = $("#search");
var listItems = $("figure");

search.on("keyup", function () {
    var terms = search.val(),
        regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(terms), 'i');
    if (terms == '') {
        listItems.show();
    } else {
        listItems.hide();
        $("figure").filter(function () {
            return regex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8pd9hfdx/2/)